# Почему происходит перенаправление на new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Контроллер для создания комментария:

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @comment = Comment.new
 end

 def create
   @comment = Comment.new(comments_params)
   @comment = current_user.comments.create

   if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "New comment was successufly added"
      redirect_to film_sessions_path
    else
      render 'new'
   end
 end

private

   def comments_params
     params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
   end

end
```

Форма:

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comments from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="well bs-component comments">
      <%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group is-empty">
           <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Comment:</label>
           <div class="col-md-10">
             <%= f.text_area :body, class:"form-control" %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
           <%= link_to 'Back', film_sessions_path, class:"btn btn-raised btn-default" %>
           <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-raised btn-primary m20" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="navi-btns">
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

При нажатии на submit происходит перенаправление на new с ошибкой - Body can't be blank, хотя поле body я заполнял

**Logs**

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-23 21:46:51 +0300
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"N92z79EAk5w3f1UwpjEiDy3x4PIPoMFVWR3LbfBJqUMGCOzzPJyPt+yzAtaFtzCuOoMcBShGKr+423nm8ZSMUw==", "comment"=>{"body"=>"test comment"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 (0.1ms)  commit transaction
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (2.7ms)
Rendered comments/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.8ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 132ms (Views: 120.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: За ссылку спасибо, полезно.
Когда добавлял комментарий в консоли, то заполнял такие поля: 
f = FilmSession.last
u = User.last
f.comments << Comment.new(user_id: u.id, body: "comment body"), больше ничего не добавлял, или вы не это имели ввиду?
При генерации страницы сначала приходит Parameters: {"day"=>"2016-06-01", "session_time"=>"09.00", "id"=>"1"}, а потом Completed 400 Bad Request in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: comment

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, комментарий начинает добавляться сразу при загрузке экшена show, а не при нажатии на submit формы?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: С @comment.commentable_type ошибся, при создании у поля был тип integer, string.

Comment: Опять обновил вопрос, действительно глупо вышло.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Что не так на этот раз?)

Comment: Ну, как минимум две попытки создать комментарий в одном методе ._.

Comment: Да, действительно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.create(comments_params)
    @comment.commentable_id = session[:id]
    @comment.commentable_type = session[:type]

    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "New comment was successufly added"
      redirect_to film_sessions_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def comments_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```